# Flask in GAE: respond quickly and then do some lengthy work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I need to respond to a request in flask fast, and then do a lengthy (possibly multi-minute) task just after.

I found the streaming response:

```
@app.route('/new_data_notification', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def push_data():
...
def stream():
    yield "OK"
    updateData()

return Response(stream(), mimetype="text/plain")
```

but it didn't work. I need it to close the request response after it said `OK`, so it doesn't time out.

EDIT: turns out I have another problem. The code is part of an app engine project, so threading is not allowed.

Comment: [Taskqueues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) maybe?

Comment: Threading **is** allowed if `app.yaml` specifies `runtime: python27` and
`threadsafe: yes`.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/background_thread for threads that can outlive the request spawning them.  (Though pushing tasks to task queues is often a superior alternative, as @SeanVieira implies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sean Vieira's TaskQueue comment I found deferred functions in app engine.

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
deferred.defer(my_func, arg0, arg1, ...)
```

this basically waits an unknown time, usually less than a few minutes, before calling the function with the supplied arguments. Works great and does not require threading. Just make sure `my_func` and all arguments are picklable and that you don't rely on modifying your path to make (this part of) your app work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a message queue (such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/)) or a thread to run this task outside of the request / response process.

Just submit the task before returning your response:

```
import threading

@app.route('/new_data_notification', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def push_data():

def stream():
    # Using threads
    threading.Thread(target=updateData).start()
    # Or, using RQ
    # q.enqueue(updateData)
    return Response("OK", mimetype="text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Taskqueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push)'s for this type of thing. It's very easy. Sounds intimidating but it's not. Unlike user requests, tasks run in the taskqueue are not bound to the 60 second time limit.

For example - here is the controller code that triggers a blob parsing task I run in a queue:

```
  blobparser_queue = taskqueue.Queue('blobparser')
  new_task = taskqueue.Task(url='/task/parse_blob/', params={'account_id': account_id,'blob_id': str(blobresource_id)},method='GET')
  blobparser_queue.add(new_task)
```

That adds a new task to my named queue, blobparser. It passes all those params to the URL supplied, and runs the task. I highly recommend it.